# How to have a rounded border with only 3 sides?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I add a rounded border for only 3 sides of the box? It's giving me errors if i add an "only" per sides if there is a border radius included.

[image]

this is my Code

```
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color:Colors.grey, width: 2.5),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
  ),
  child: child,
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Container with 3 borders and radiuses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72993462/container-with-3-borders-and-radiuses)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't quite get the screenshot but to have border for three sides, say for only left, right and bottom, use:

```dart
final borderSide = BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2);

Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      left: borderSide,
      right: borderSide,
      bottom: borderSide,
    ),
  ),
  child: child,
)
```

Comment: You cannot use border radius in this case - will get an exception "A borderRadius can only be given for a uniform Border."

Answer (score 1):

simply use .only in place of .circular

```
Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color:Colors.grey, width: 2.5),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(13.0),topRight: Radius.circular(13.0)),
    ),
    child: child,
  )
```

Similarly you can add bottomLeft and bottomRight in .only

Comment: Border.all(color:Colors.grey, width: 2.5)  will draw 4 borders, the question is how to have 3 borders + radius